# Webview back button problem (stack multiple clicks)

Tags: java, android, android-webview

i have back button in my webview and its linked with loading screen (when i click back button its show loading animation (its named progressBar in the code).
But i have problem when i make fast few clicks my loading screen is looping.
Its any way to make the back button work only one time on page?
Like 1 click = 1 action, no more and stack.
For example i click on the back button, and its off for next click, but when page reloaded button work again.

```
Button przycisk_powrot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.przycisk_powrot);
        przycisk_powrot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mywebView.goBack();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



            }
        }); 

Button przycisk_powrot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.przycisk_powrot);
        przycisk_powrot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mywebView.goBack();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



            }
        });

 @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(mywebView.canGoBack()) {
            mywebView.goBack();

        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
    public class WebViewClient extends android.webkit.WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            }, 1000);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);


        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);



        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            boolean overrideUrlLoading = false;
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: That's not JavaScript. [JavaScript is not Java](http://javascriptisnotjava.com/)